# Yii URL Management HTTPS

Tags: php, yii

Im using a code to separate pages that is HTTPS and HTTP in my website

The problem is: When Im on HTTP, links to HTTPS no have WWW and vice versa.
I did not find the problem in the script.

```
public function createUrl($route, $params = array(), $ampersand = '&')
{
    $url = parent::createUrl($route, $params, $ampersand);

    // If already an absolute URL, return it directly
    if (strpos($url, 'http') === 0) {
        return $url;  
    }

    // Check if the current protocol matches the expected protocol of the route
    // If not, prefix the generated URL with the correct host info.
    $secureRoute = $this->isSecureRoute($route);
    if (Yii::app()->request->isSecureConnection) {
        return $secureRoute ? $url : 'http://' . Yii::app()->request->serverName . $url;
    } else {
        return $secureRoute ? 'https://' . Yii::app()->request->serverName . $url : $url;
    }
}

public function parseUrl($request)
{
    $route = parent::parseUrl($request);

    // Perform a 301 redirection if the current protocol 
    // does not match the expected protocol
    $secureRoute = $this->isSecureRoute($route);
    $sslRequest = $request->isSecureConnection;
    if ($secureRoute !== $sslRequest) {
        $hostInfo = $secureRoute ? 'https://' . Yii::app()->request->serverName : 'http://' . Yii::app()->request->serverName;
        if ((strpos($hostInfo, 'https') === 0) xor $sslRequest) {
            $request->redirect($hostInfo . $request->url, true, 301);
        }
    }
    return $route;
}

private $_secureMap;

/**
 * @param string the URL route to be checked
 * @return boolean if the give route should be serviced in SSL mode
 */
protected function isSecureRoute($route)
{
    if ($this->_secureMap === null) {
        foreach ($this->secureRoutes as $r) {
            $this->_secureMap[strtolower($r)] = true;
        }
    }
    $route = strtolower($route);
    if (isset($this->_secureMap[$route])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return ($pos = strpos($route, '/')) !== false 
            && isset($this->_secureMap[substr($route, 0, $pos)]);
    }
}
```

}

Code adapted from: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages/

Comment: You try using createAbsoluteUrl function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to manage this at the controller level using filters.

In your components directory setup 2 filters `HttpsFilter` and `HttpFilter` as follows:-

```
class HttpsFilter extends CFilter {

    protected function preFilter( $filterChain ) {
        if ( !Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection ) {
            # Redirect to the secure version of the page.
            $url = 'https://' .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->serverName .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri;
                Yii::app()->request->redirect($url);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

and

```
class HttpFilter extends CFilter {

    protected function preFilter( $filterChain ) {
        if ( Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection ) {
            # Redirect to the secure version of the page.
                $url = 'http://' .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->serverName .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri;
                Yii::app()->request->redirect($url);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 
}
```

then in each controller force https using the filters, optionally by action:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {

    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'https +index', // Force https, but only on login page
        );
    }
}
```

Edit: if the `filters()` function above doesn't seem to work for you, instead try

```
return array(
           array('HttpsFilter +index'), // Force https, but only on login page
       );
```

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter (and comments on it).