# Yii urlManger when working with subdomains

Tags: yii, subdomain

I want to ask about pecularities of Yii urlManger when you are working with a module, which was assigned a subdomain.

**Here is what I need to do:**

I need to put "login", "signup", "book" and some other actions behind SSL, and for some reason SSL certificate is signed for a subdomain eg online.example.com.

I've created a Yii module "secure" for all actions which require SSL, and assigned a sub-domain "online.exmaple.com" to it as follows:

```
'https:// online.example.com/<action:(signin|signup)>'  
  => 'secure/default/<action>',
```

Now the tricky things..

**1. How can I createUrl() from this module back to the site?**

For example: createUrl('site/idex') from module would create url: 'https:// online.example.com/site/index'
And I need an url back to 'http:// example.com/site/index'.

Currently I do a workaround:

```
'http://'.$mainDomain . '/'         => 'site/index', 
'http://'.$mainDomain . '/news'      =>'site/news',
```

where $mainDomain is just fixed 'example.com' string.
But this doesn't always work.
For example it doesn't work for returnUrl

```
Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl(array('site/index'));
```

will get me to 'https:// online.example.com/secure/site/index'

and the second important question:

**2. How to restrict subdomain ONLY to serve the module linked to it?**

Now for example, if I go
'https:// online.example.com/site/index' (note: default action for module would be 'default/index') it will get me to my site homepage. It shouldn't.
or I can access any other module with:
'https:// online.example.com/mymodule/default/index'

That shouldn't work this way!
Sub-domain assigned to module should serve only that module.

I can't find anything usefull in documentation. Maybe somebody have some ideas, how to deal with that?

Comment: The following post I found in a quick search has a nice solution using controller filters @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014732/yii-url-management-https

Answer (score 0):

1) createUrl('online/site/index')

2) routes:
"http:// online.".$domain."/site/index"=>'online/site/index'